# pasar dato JSON a un textview

Tags: php, java, android-studio, json

Buenos dias compañeros y expertos, hoy traigo una duda ante ustedes que ya hizo que me doliera la cabeza, y estoy a punto de arrojar la pc contra la pared, estoy tratando de pasar los datos que obtengo de una consulta en mysql y que se descarga en JSON, son tres datos, nombre telefono y mail. se descargan bien, pero quiero pasarlos a textview o a edittext pero no puedo ya lo intente y lo reintente y no puedo, podrian darme un empjoncito, les dejo mi codigo de main y el webservice en php
Main AndroidStudio

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText et3;
Button bot3;
TextView textView;
JSONObject jsonObject=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        et3=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et3);
        bot3=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bot3);

        bot3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Thread tr=new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final String respu=enviarPost(et3.getText().toString());
                    try{
                        JSONArray json=new JSONArray(respu);

                        final ListView list1=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
                        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arrayList=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
                        HashMap<String,String>hashMap;
                        try{
                            jsonObject=json.getJSONObject(0);
                            textView.setText(jsonObject.getString("nombre"));



                        }catch (Exception e){}
                    }catch (Exception e){}
                }
            };
            tr.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public String enviarPost(String et3){
        String parametros= "cliente="+et3;
        HttpURLConnection connection=null;
        String respuesta="";
        try{
            URL url=new URL("http://192.168.0.6/cliente.php");
            connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Lenght",""+Integer.toString(parametros.getBytes().length));
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr=new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(parametros);
            wr.close();

            Scanner inStream =new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
            while (inStream.hasNextLine())
                respuesta+=(inStream.nextLine());

        }catch (Exception e){}

        return respuesta.toString();
    }
}
```

y este es el WS en php

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$puerto = "3306";
$usuario = "root";
$contrasena = "root";
$baseDeDatos ="24huser";
$tabla = "clientes";
function Conectarse()
{global $host, $puerto, $usuario, $contrasena, $baseDeDatos, $tabla;
   if (!($link = mysqli_connect($host.":".$puerto, $usuario, $contrasena))) 
   { exit(); }
   if (!mysqli_select_db($link, $baseDeDatos)) 
   { exit(); }
return $link; } 
$link = Conectarse(); 
$cliente=$_REQUEST['cliente'];
if ($cliente!=null){
    //echo "entro 1";
    $resultado = mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT nombre,telefono,email FROM clientes WHERE id = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado, "i", $cliente);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($resultado);
    if(!$resultado or (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($resultado)==0)){}
    else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($resultado,$a1,$a2, $a3);
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($resultado)) {
        $datos=array('nombre'=>$a1,'telefono'=>$a2,'email'=>$a3);}
        echo json_encode(array($datos));
        }
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

el resultado de ese ws es algo asi:

```
[{"nombre":"luishdz","telefono":"8880001111","email":"nada1@gmail.com"}]
```

Por favor ayudenme necesito mostrar la informacion de este JSON ya sea en multiples textview o en un listview, de verdad les voy a agradecer muchisimo su ayuda, porfavor!!!

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema que no puedes agregarlo a un TextView, al parecer no se tiene error en el código? o lo que deseas es que se agreguen en varios TextView? ¿que no funciona?

Comment: " son tres datos, nombre telefono y mail. se descargan bien, pero quiero pasarlos a textview o a edittext " , tres datos a dos elementos, no se entiende como quieres distribuir la información.

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys gracias por tomarte el tiempo, trato de que aparezca en el textview, en este caso intento con el primer objeto, que es nombre pero cuando lo corro no me aparece al presionar el boton, no cambia el valor.

Comment: Hola @ErickCastillo , que valor tienes en el EditText et3 cuando realizas la petición? la petición funciona en base a este valor.

Comment: @Jorgesys en este ejemplo aparece el texto name pero lo borro y le pongo el número 1 y presionó buscar